# How to block a page for certain countries (geoip2) without if?

Tags: nginx, ip, centos7, geoip, geoip2

How it is possible without using **if** but with **map** in nginx with the module --with_geoip2_module (dynamic) to block all countries except the chosen and all ip except the chosen, to make it work like this:

```
**if ($lan = yes) {
              set $allowed_country yes;
      }

if ($allowed_country = no) {
       return 503;
  }**
```

but without **if**?

**Centos 7**

It`s my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip2_module.so;

user nginx;

worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

#block country

 geoip2 /etc/nginx/geoip/GeoLite2-Country/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb {

auto_reload 60m;
$geoip2_data_country_code country iso_code;
$geoip2_data_country_name country names en;
}  

geo $lan {
 default no;
 123.224.55.2 yes;

  }


map $geoip2_data_country_code $allowed_country {
    
    default no;
    UA yes;
    BG yes;
    RO yes;
}

   log_format geoip_main '$remote_addr - $geoip2_data_country_code - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                           '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$host" '
                           '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log geoip_main;

access_log /var/log/nginx/geoip_country.log geoip_main;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

access_log /var/log/nginx/geoip_country.log geoip_main;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
 include include/etc/nginx/modules/*.so;

}
```

I am very grateful to you for your help!

Comment: I don't think it is possible at all. Anyway you shouldn't worry about `if (...) { return 503; }` block, it is completely safe. You can use an additional `map` directive instead your first `if` block.

Comment: thanks for the answer and how can I write this for the second directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An official NGINX article [says](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/):

> The only 100% safe things which may be done inside if in a location context are:
>
> ```
> return ...;
> rewrite ... last;
> ```

So your `if (...) { return 503; }` block is completely safe. To exclude first one `if` block, use

```
geo $lan {
    default no;
    123.224.55.2 yes;
}
map $geoip2_data_country_code $allowed_country {
    default no;
    UA yes;
    BG yes;
    RO yes;
}
map $lan$allowed_country $deny {
    ~yes "";
    default 1;
}
...
server {
    ...
    if ($deny) {
        return 503;
    }
    ...
}
```

**Update**

This version have the same functionality and should be slightly faster since it doesn't use a regex matching:

```
geo $lan {
    default  0;
    123.224.55.2  1;
    ...
}
map $geoip2_data_country_code $allowed_country {
    default  0;
    UA  1;
    BG  1;
    RO  1;
}
map $lan$allowed_country $deny {
    default  0;
    00  1;
}
...
server {
    ...
    if ($deny) {
        return 503;
    }
    ...
}
```